# How Do You Fix: Use of undeclared type 'NSFetchRequest'?

Tags: ios, swift

I am a beginner with swift and I'm trying to complete my first app. While I  was writing a code, I saw it say:

> Use of undeclared type 'NSFetchRequest'.

My lines of code:

```
override  func viewWillAppear(_ animated: bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

            let fetchRequest = Birthday.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest = Birthday
    do{
        birthdays = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

`import CoreData`

and change the fetch request line to

```
let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Birthday> = Birthday.fetchRequest()
```

Comment: This didn't work. When I typed    import CoreData and   let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Birthday> = Birthday.fetchRequest() it would show two errors. 'Declaration is only valid at file scope' and  'Use of undeclared type 'NSFetchRequest''

Comment: The `import` line must be on the top of the file outside of the controller class.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Actually *on the top of the file outside of the controller class* is pretty specific. Please look into your `AppDelegate` class. There is an `import` line. The `import CoreData` line must be on the **same** level or scope, that's exactly what *is only valid at file scope* means.